# Deal with AJAX when importing websites

Tags: web-access

I'm currently planning to create a small package to enable Mathematica to manipulate [WeChat](https://wx.qq.com/), a extremely famous chatting software in China.

The first step is to get the QRCode on the website, but the QR is automatically updated once a few minute and use AJAX, so a direct `URLFetch` or `Import` won't work, also `Import["https://wx.qq.com/","JSON"]` failed on my computer too.

I can get a proper HTML result using the developer tool on my web browser:
[image: proper]

But the automatically updated QRCode address part(the selected region on the previous screenshot) cannot be fetched by Mathematica easily (due to AJAX)

[image: not good]

The QRCode address part of this small HTML segment is replaced.

So how can I get a HTML result **just like what I get in my web browser** regardless of all AJAX or other stuffs? Thanks!

---

related:

There're existing packages in Python: [itchat](https://github.com/littlecodersh/ItChat)

[How to execute JavaScipt on a webpage and then import the result on OSX?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57587/how-to-execute-javascipt-on-a-webpage-and-then-import-the-result-on-osx)
(note that the method given in this question cannot solve my problem, even though I use windows os)

Comment: The only way to generate the HTML you see in a browser is to actually evaluate the website source code as a browser. [WebUnit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/web-browsing-automation-with-mathematica) can maybe be used, but I've never used it so I'm not sure. I talked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143779/731) about using Chrome's developer tool to find out where the data is coming from. The idea is to use that, and then download the data from there directly.

Comment: It's not clear to me which JSON file you are trying to import, in your case it seems that you are wanting to find the URL of an image?

Comment: @C.E. yup, and in further cases maybe I will need to fetch some other contents, e.g. messages and links. so the main goal is to fetch the HTML. That comment is useless, sorry...... I misunderstood your post